# Solr: How to do DISTINCT(field1, field2, field3) search on documents with many fields?

Tags: solr, distinct, facet, faceted-search

For doing a Solr search:  Imagine I have documents that have 6 fields each.  I want to search on conditions of 2 fields, return those fields along with a 3rd and 4th field only (instead of all 6 fields).  So the response will be a set of documents with a subset of 4 fields each.

Since the four fields is a subset of all documents, how can I get only the distinct sets of those 4 fields with no duplicates across that set of 4 fields?

To demonstrate, say we have the following documents with fields A, B, C, D, E, and F:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F
1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,2,2,1,1
1,1,2,3,4,5
2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Then I want to query for only fields A,B,E,F where A=1 and B=1

The result would be:

```
A-B-E-F
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,4,5
```

However, I want to remove the duplicates and want to achieve the reduced response:

```
A-B-E-F
1,1,1,1
1,1,4,5
```

Is this possible in Solr?  If so, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Pivot faceting on `E` and `F` with `A:1 AND B:1` as the `fq` should work?

Comment: If you only need to check uniqueness for a small number of fields, i.e. just `E` and `F` (or a small combination of C, D, E, F - index their combinations as separate fields concatenated together - it'll make it very effective to check for uniqueness.